Find $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+3x^2}} dx$
How can I solve the following integral?
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1+3x^2 }} dx$$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hint: let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \sinh t$. Can you finish?

A similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127394/how-to-caluclate-the-integral-of-int-frac1-sqrt4x21dx-using-a-trig?noredirect=1.

Under $x=\frac{\tan(u)}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $dx=\frac{\sec^2(u)}{\sqrt{3}}$ the integral becomes:
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\sec(u)du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\int\frac{\sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u)}{\sec(u)+\tan(u)}du$$
Substitute $s=\tan(u)+\sec(u)$ and $ds=(\sec^2(u)+\tan(u)\sec(u))du$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{1}{s}ds=\frac{\log(s)}{\sqrt{3}}+C=\frac{\log(\tan(u)+\sec(u))}{\sqrt{3}}+C\\=\frac{\log(\tan(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3}x))+\sec(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3}x)))}{\sqrt{3}}+C\\=\frac{\log(\sqrt{3x^2+1}+\sqrt{3}x)}{\sqrt{3}}$$
NOTE: Wolfram alpha gives $I=\frac{\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{3}x)}{\sqrt{3}}$. Which , for restricted values of $x$ ,is equivalent to our result.

Please don't answer questions that lack context. It goes against the rules of this site. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards
